# "illegal value" error on cck field

Tags: entities

I have a select list in content profile which is having list of counties value. when i submit the user profile form, there is an error throwing like "Counties: illegal value" . I checked the Allowed values list: in cck settings having correct format. Anyone can say the fix for this error.

Comment: Could you show the actual error (in full) and any code you're using, especially any JavaScript manipulation you're doing on the form?

Comment: Thanks for your reply clive, No i didnt use any code or any javascript manipulation . its a normal profile content type and i have created a filed in manage fields which the name is "Counties" belongs to the type "select list" and having options in allowed values. when the user submit the profile form it throws an error "Counties: illegal value"

Comment: If that's the full error then it's not coming from Drupal core (Drupal core has one similar but nothing that short). I'd start disabling contrib/custom modules methodically until you find the culprit

Comment: Clive : Am trying to find the reason for this "illegal value" error but no results. Please tell me what will happen if once i disable and enable the CCK module for fix this error. Is this job will destroy old records and tables in DATABASE ?